# Serious Packet Loss on UDP using Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, udp, sip

I am using ec2 to host a udp TURN server for SIP purpose. Anyway I get a lot of packet loss during voice call, so I did a udp performance test using iperf util.

Result:

```
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[  3]  0.0-10.3 sec   434 KBytes   345 Kbits/sec  28.910 ms 2249/ 2551 (88%)
[  4] local 10.128.99.128 port 5001 connected with 175.139.254.157 port 50900
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   617 KBytes   505 Kbits/sec   7.834 ms  463/  893 (52%)
```

The result was terrible as when i send a 3MB file, 88% of packet loss.
I tried to play around with sysctl to tune UDP performance, but no matter what value i used, the result is still the same.

Sysctl:

```
net.core.wmem_max=26214400
net.core.rmem_max=26214400
net.ipv4.udp_mem= 10240 87380 12582912
net.core.netdev_max_backlog=2000
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: the question is "how to tune amazon ec2 udp performance?"

Comment: @Jason - I am trying to do something VERY SIMILAR to what you are doing.  Did you ever get a resolution for hosting TURN server on EC2?

Comment: no resolution yet

Answer (score -1):

Can you run latency checks on your hosted machines, latencies from outside ec2 into your box?  VOIP is so dependent on performance,  and instance zones can have issues from minute to minute that might make VOIP perform badly.